# Python 2 regex operations from re package not handling utf-8 diacritic encoding

Tags: python, regex, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm performing a series of regex operations on a `utf-8` encoded text file that contains a list of lines containing alphabetic and non-alphabetic characters, including non-Latin characters with diacritics. This is a snippet from the file (notice the non-Latin characters):

```
oro[=]sia[=]łeś
oszust[=]ką
```

My script first opens the text file, reads each line and strips the unnecessary characters. My regex operations then first catch a word matching a specified pattern and then either insert of adjust the position of the non-alphabetical character groups `[=]`. This is a snippet from my script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

with open(r'...\input.txt', "rb") as input, open(r'...\output.txt', "wb") as output:

for line in input:

    word = line.strip('\r\n')

    # Rule 1: ^VCV -> V[=]CV
    match = re.match('^[AEIOUYaeiouy]([bcćdfghjklłmnńprsśtwzżź]|rz|sz|cz|dz|dż|dź|ch)[aąeęioóuy].*(.*\[=\].*)*', word)
    result = match.group() if match else None

    if result == word:
        word = re.sub('(?<=^[AEIOUYaeiouy])(?=([bcćdfghjklłmnńprsśtwzżź]|rz|sz|cz|dz|dż|dź|ch)[aąeęioóuy])', '[=]', word)

     outLine = word + "\n"        
     errorList.write(outLine)
```

The rule seems to fail with inputs with rule environments that involve non-Latin characters with diacritics. For example, when the input to Rule 1 above is `'oszust[=]ką'`, `re.match.group()` re-encodes it as `'oszust[=]k\xc4'`. Converting the last character changes the environment and matches the input for the following regex operation.

The problem clearly lies in `utf-8` encoding, because the script manages to process `oro[=]sia[=]łeś`, where the rule environment does not contain characters with diacritics, just fine. Having read [this](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/unicode.html) website, I tried re-encoding the input to `utf-8` so that it meets the environment for the regex operation, but instead I get this error:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Why does the error mention `ascii` if I'm trying to encode it as `utf-8`? How can I modify the encoding so that it meets the environment required for the regex operation?

Comment: What python version are you using? You might want to try specifying an encoding at the top of your file.

Comment: I'm using Python 2. I forgot to add the top line when pasting my code into the question. The issue persists even when you specify # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- in the header.

Comment: You shouldn't be opening files in binary mode if you want to work with Unicode characters, unless you're willing to do the decode/encode yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with Unicode characters, use Unicode strings.  Convert to/from Unicode strings at the I/O boundaries of your program.  Switch to the latest Python 3 if possible.  It handles Unicode much better.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import io

with io.open('input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as input, \
    io.open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as output:

    for line in input:
        word = line.strip()  # this will remove all leading/trailing whitespace.

        # Rule 1: ^VCV -> V[=]CV
        match = re.match(u'^[AEIOUYaeiouy]([bcćdfghjklłmnńprsśtwzżź]|rz|sz|cz|dz|dż|dź|ch)[aąeęioóuy].*(.*\[=\].*)*', word)
        result = match.group() if match else None

        if result == word:
            word = re.sub(u'(?<=^[AEIOUYaeiouy])(?=([bcćdfghjklłmnńprsśtwzżź]|rz|sz|cz|dz|dż|dź|ch)[aąeęioóuy])', u'[=]', word)

        outLine = word + u'\n'        
        output.write(outLine)
```